# moisture barrier for an indoor swimming pool

Tags: cement

What is the proper way to install wall boards with a water barrier? I am concerned about moisture escaping into walls. I'm istalling an indoor swimming pool and am concerned about moisture.

Comment: Indoor pools can really be a tough project. I have found stucco to be the best indoor option. The high humidity with a heated pool is a part of life, venting while using the pool also makes a difference. If we know more about the climate and the planed water temp we may be able to provide other options.

Comment: Indoor swimming pools - in a regular residence make sure you really research what you are doing (if it is in a separate building you are probably fine.. home values do not always get enhanced by an indoor pool feature and sometimes they can go unsold for years if done wrong. There is a fully remodeled house for sale in my neighborhood with an indoor pool; it has been on the market for 4 years now. Plenty of other homes have sold even next to and across the street from that one. Just an FYI..